# How can i show asynchronously gotten information in a dialog box using dojo and struts2?

Tags: ajax, struts2, dojo

I'm building a code, using Struts2 and Dojo for Ajax support. I'm trying to launch a dialog box when certain link is used. This dialog box should contain information that is gotten asynchronously when said link is cliked.

Here is my code:

```
<s:url id="buscar_usuarios_url" value="/buscar_usuarios.action"/>
<li id="menu_buscar_usuarios"><sx:a targets="buscar_usuarios_dialog" href="%{buscar_usuarios_url}">Buscar usuarios</sx:a></li>
```

This piece of code gets the html i need to show in the dialog box i'm using in this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#menu_buscar_usuarios").live('click', function() {
        $("#buscar_usuarios_dialog").dialog({
            modal:true
        });
   });
}
```

The problem i have is that when i click the < sx:a > tag, only the information is gotten but the dialog box doesn't show up. Whereas when i click in the < li > just outside the < a > only the dialog box is shown but the information is not updated.

I tried to give the id "menu_buscar_usuarios" to the < sx:a > tag but it doesn't work either, what should i do?

Comment: what is the error when you give sx:a the id "menu_buscar_usuarios"

Comment: please add this as answer and accept it after 48 hours, will help someone in future

Comment: Yes, i tried to. I don't have enough reputation so i will just have to wait 6 hours. I'll do it then. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for your effort to help others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I just gave the < sx:tag > the id "menu_buscar_usuarios" and instead of use the live() function, which is deprecated, i used the on() function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#menu_buscar_usuarios").live('click', function() {
        $("#buscar_usuarios_dialog").dialog({
            modal:true
        });
   });
}
```

Thank you all